# Pagination/offset using Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am using a REST API to pull down information.  It returns a max of 100 records and returns a boolean (is there more) and an offset (what to pass to next call for where to start).  I was able to create the one time pull of records from the API to a SQL DB no problem.  I want to now check the boolean and pass the offset into the next call.  I had the thought to call the same logic app in a sort of recursive matter but I am not seeing where to set parameters for an HTTP request/action.

Here is what I am currently doing

[image: initial]

and this is what I am intending to do

[image]

I was reading the documentation for [http endpoint in a logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint) but I am not seeing anything for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it should work if you put all of that above inside an Until loop that repeats until more pages == false. Now the tricky part will be setting the offset every time, as our variables today only support increment and decrement. Set Value for variables should roll out in next week or two and you could set the value of the offset to the variable. In the meantime you could store the offset in any external state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and update on variables @jeffhollan.  I tried to initialize the offset in the while but was given the error "The operation 'Initialize variable' can only be used at top level."  The biggest problem I keep coming across is how do I take a value from the request and pass it into the next one?

Comment: You would use 'Initialize variable' for the part outside the loop. Inside the loop, you would use 'Set variable'.